# Macro To Clear Contents of a Data Validation Cell IF Specific Cell Formula Changes it's Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data validation list in cell N6. 
The list is: housing, regulars, builders, private.

Cell M8 has the formula: =IF(N6="Housing","Grade:"," ")

There is a data validation list in cell N8. 
The list is: FIRST, SECOND, THIRD.

I'd like to be able to clear cell N8 if cell N6 is changed or cleared.
I have tried this VBA code, but it doesn't clear cell N8 as intended:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N6")) Is Nothing Then
If Range("N6") <> "" Then Range("N8").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried this VBA code, but it also doesn't clear cell N8.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$N6")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("N8").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

Please help me get this right.

Comment: Disable events if you are going to change a value on the worksheet.

Comment: Are you sure you meant **M8** and why the space in `" "` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab and choose View Code),

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N6")) Is Nothing Then
        application.enableevents = false
        Range("N8") = vbnullstring
        application.enableevents = true
    End If

End Sub
```

Previous errant attempts may have left events disabled. Put `application.enableevents = true` into the VBE's Immediate window and hit enter.

Comment: do I replace "application.enableevents = false" with "application.enableevents = true"? Thanks